# Тип : словарь. Задать значение переменной в текстовом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, типы

Цель : хочу сделать значение переменной в текстовом файле.

Для этого я создал код и текстовый файл. В текстовом файле к примеру написано - `{"Ex":None}` - затем, я "открываю" файл, и вывожу тип и содержимое.

Получая тип : str - что не удивительно, но мне необходимо получить тип : словарь.

Как это реализовать, если типы не сходятся?

Comment: Если хотите положить/получить объект из файла, то открывайте на запись/чтение файл в режиме 'wb'/'rb'

Comment: получился тип : Bytes. как получить тип : словарь ?

Comment: с текущим форматом записи единственный вариант: `my_dict = eval(file.read())`. однако этот способ крайне небезопасный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо понимать, что текстовый файл хранит просто последовательность байт и он ничего знать не знает ни про какие типы, словари и т.п.

Если вы хотите сохранять питоновские объекты в файл, а потом получать их оттуда, то вам может помочь модуль `pickle`.

Сначала из какого-то первого питоновского скрипта мы записываем объект в файл:

```
import pickle

data = {"Ex": None}

with open('example.txt', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data, file)
```

В результате у нас создаётся файл `example.txt`, который хранит в себе ваш словарь. Словарь хранится в особом формате, поэтому просто так "глазами" прочитать его не получится. Если вы откроете этот файл, то вы увидите что-то такое: `�}q X   ExqNs.`

Дальше вы можете это преобразовать обратно в ваш словарь вот так (это можно делать уже из совсем другого скрипта):

```
import pickle

with open('example.txt', 'rb') as file:
    readed_data = pickle.load(file)
    print(type(readed_data), readed_data)

# Напечатает: <class 'dict'> {'Ex': None}
```

Comment: Если я напишу в текстовый файл вручную текст, то с помощью модуля можно изъять его?

Comment: Как я уже написал выше, pickle использует свой особый формат. Вручную в таком формате писать сложно. Если хочется именно написать в файл объект так же, как он пишется в питоновском коде, то остаётся только eval - пример вам привели в комментариях под вопросом. Но обычно его использование нежелательно. Тут хотелось бы увидеть целиком вашу задачу, чтобы понять, что вам лучше посоветовать.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее подходящим способом хранения будет JSON.
Это способ хранения в текстовом представлении типичных данных - словари, массивы, числа, строки и т.п.

```
import json

data = {"Ex":None}
with open('output.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(data, fout, ensure_ascii = False, indent = 4)
```

у функции `dump` используются следующие параметры:

- data -  объект Python
- fout - файловый поток (файл, который мы открыли)
- ensure_ascii= False - нужно, чтобы работать корректно с utf-8 кодировкой
- indent=4 - количество отступов при сериализации, чтобы разметка файла выглядела читабельно.

Результатом такого представления будет файл с именем `output.json` и следующим содержимым

```
{
    "Ex": null
}
```